# Statistical tests for comparing simulation behavior to real world behavior

Tags: simulation, confusion-matrix

In summary: given confusion matrices (TP/TN/FP/FN) from 8 runs on real data and x runs on simulated data, show that the results from simulated data behaves similar to that of the real data.

More detail:
I'm working on project of sorting/classifying mineral ores for my research (in Computer Science). I take data from sensors and, using an algorithm I developed, classify ores into 2 categories. In end this leaves me with a count of TP/TN/FP/FN for every run (I've collected data from 8 runs).

I've also built a simulator which aims to create data similar to that of the real ores passing over real sensors. The simulation is very much an approximation, and the data in produces I already know has its differences from the real data.

What I want to state is that the results (the TP/TN/FP/FN classifications) from running the algorithm on real data is comparable to running the same algorithm on simulated data. That is, that the behavior of my algorithm is the same on both the real data and simulated data. For instance, if my algorithm performs well on simulated data, I want to state with some assurance that it will perform well on real data as well.

I'm looking for a statistical test to help support this statement.

Note: I can collect as much data as needed from simulation, but am restricted to in the real world tests (prefer not to do more than the 8 I have already).

Any ideas of what statistical tests I can use?

I don't have a background in statistics, so any suggestions - even trivial ones - would be appreciated.